# MongoDB Aggregation with sum of identical array elements how to?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am building statistics on most used combination of cards, this I can do easily by unwinding $players and grouping with _id of $players.spells.d -- it works quite fast and gives me exactly what I want.

The issue I have is I cannot figure out how to take into consideration the level of the card. (Cards can be upgraded) -- when level is missing, it means it is level 1. So what I would like to get in the end is the deck id (a combination of all the cards, they are already sorted so no need to do any magic tricks, already generated with $players.spells.d grouping below), with the average level of each individual card for that combination.

This is my query:

```
db.matches.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$players"},
    {$group: {
            '_id': '$players.spells.card',
            'count': {'$sum' : 1}
        }
    },
    {$sort: {'count' : -1}}
]);
```

Here's what a match document look like, each match has 2 players:

```
{
    "_id" : 123,
    "players" : [
        {
            "id" : 41,
            "spells" : [
                {
                    "card" : 11,
                    "level" : 2
                },
                {
                    "card" : 12
                },
                {
                    "card" : 13,
                    "level" : 2
                },
                {
                    "card" : 14
                },
                {
                    "card" : 15,
                    "level" : 2
                },
                {
                    "card" : 16,
                    "level" : 2
                },
                {
                    "card" : 17,
                    "level" : 2
                },
                {
                    "card" : 18
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : 31,
            "spells" : [
                {
                    "card" : 7
                },
                {
                    "card" : 88
                },
                {
                    "card" : 9
                },
                {
                    "card" : 10
                },
                {
                    "card" : 11
                },
                {
                    "card" : 12
                },
                {
                    "card" : 13
                },
                {
                    "card" : 14
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: what is deck id and what is players.spells.d ?

Comment: I updated the query above, d was supposed to be card, I was making things easier to read for everybody and forgot that one spot :)

Answer (score 0):

here you go :

```
db.matches.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$players"},
    {$unwind:"$players.spells"},
    {$group:{"_id":"$players.id","count":{"$sum":"$players.spells.card"}}
}])
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but not a solution :( it looks like you missed the part where _id should be the concatenation of all the card ids, not the player id, and I am interested to know the average level of each card which is missing from your query above.

Comment: db.testC.aggregate([{$unwind: "$players"},{$unwind:"$players.spells"},{$group:
{"_id":"$_id","count":{"$sum":"$players.spells.card"},"avg":{"$avg":"$players.sp
ells.level"}}}]);

Comment: you need to add level to all the cards, also level 1. or you'll need to make part of the operation in the application, to check whether the level exist or not.

Comment: I can add level 1, sure that is not a problem. But that solution still does not give me what I want :(

the _id should be something like "[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]" (an array of the cards used in the deck by a specific player, that's why I mentionned using $players.spells.card for grouping) so I can count how many occurrence of this exact deck occurs, how popular that exact deck is. My original query does that. Now I want to add an average of the level for each specific card in that deck.